# How do I release ports which are being held by a notebook server after it has been stopped?

Tags: port, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm starting up a jupyter notebook server on an AWS instance (Redhat Linux server) to connect to over https. In the config file I have that this should be on port 9999. However when I stop and restart the process with Ctrl-C, the port is not being released, as shown below.

```
[user@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx notebook]$ [I 08:39:27.901 NotebookApp] The port 9999 is already in use, trying another random port.
[I 08:39:27.901 NotebookApp] The port 10000 is already in use, trying another random port.
[I 08:39:27.902 NotebookApp] The port 10001 is already in use, trying another random port.
[I 08:39:27.905 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/user/docs/notebook
[I 08:39:27.905 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels
[I 08:39:27.905 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at: https://[all ip addresses on your system]:10002/
[I 08:39:27.905 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
```

As an aside, those "random ports" don't look very random to me.

Comment: True, probably better on SuperUser (though ipython/jupyter notebook is definitely a tool used by the programming community). How do I migrate it?

Comment: are you sure the stop command actually really stops the service? can you do a stop and netstat -tlnp in a raw to check this? It is possible that the stop only deletes the pid file but actually fails to stop the service

Comment: No, it seems it's not stopping the service. So after `netstat -tlnp` I can use `kill [pid]` which seems to work. Thanks!

Comment: glad you found it :) moving this comment as an answer for potential other users

Answer (score 6, accepted):

sometimes the stop command of a service doesn't return any error and deletes the pid file of a process, but does actually not terminate the process itself.

you can check if the process is still running by running the stop command and then either

```
ps aux | grep -i notebook
```

or

```
netstat -tlnp | grep <portNumber>
```

As you stated you can then either kill the process manually, or fix the stop script (usually /etc/init.d/serviceName+d). The reason for the process to not be killed is often (not always) linked to permissions owned by the user executing the command

Comment: So I should start the server using `sudo jupyter notebook &` rather than just  `jupyter notebook &` ?

Comment: No, that can't be it. It gives me `sudo: jupyter: command not found`

Comment: usually you would prefer to dedicate a user to a service. e.g for services as apache, mysql etc., you will get a system users dedicated to run these services, with only the least privileges needed to run them. However, if security is not a big deal for you then just do what is working for you. It s hard for me to say if you should do sudo or not as I don't know neither your system settings/users/rights/path/etc nor jupyter service :)